# my list of 140 elements just print the first one

Tags: python, list, typeerror

My code prints just the first element of the list (activities), because of the 0; but, when I try `[:]` I get the '**list indices must be integers or slices, not str' type error**.

I need to print the 140 elements inside my list but I really don't know how to fix it. And I don't really want to write another code because this is the only way that I could have the difference between two dates in seconds.

This is my code:

```
import json
import datetime
import copy


#Read json

with open('/Users/kenyacastellanos/Downloads/data.json') as json_data_file:
    data = json.load(json_data_file)
print(data)

#Just show first 10 elements
print("Sin ordenar:",data['activities'][:10])

## Realizamos el ordenamiento por llave, la llave es user_id, creamos una funcion lambda para el ordenamiento
data['activities'].sort(key = lambda x: x['user_id'])

#Just show first 10 elements
print("Ordenamos:", data['activities'][:10])

# Duration
date1 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(data['activities'][:]['answered_at'])
date2 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(data['activities'][:]['first_seen_at'])
difference_date = (date1-date2)
print("Duration in seconds:", difference_date.seconds, difference_date.microseconds)
```

This is what my list contains, 140 of these. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMWlr.png)

```
"activities":[
      {
         "id":272961,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:09:53.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:09:40.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":402616,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:10:27.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:10:09.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":64828,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:13:19.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:13:03.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":397256,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:18:06.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:17:47.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":202872,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:19:00.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:18:54.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":367396,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:23:30.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:23:18.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":378117,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:25:12.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:25:05.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":257362,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:30:30.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:30:11.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":80097,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:34:23.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:34:13.830+00:00"
      },
```

Comment: Which list? There's no list in your code?

Comment: Why not just use a rudimentary `for… in` loop?

Comment: 'activities' is my list

Comment: What is this, a pandas data frame? Give us the full picture

Comment: just did, i'm sorry :(

Comment: In the future, please provide sample input data in textual form (i.e. not an image of it) if possible in your question so folks have something use for testing their answers,

Comment: thank u so much, i just updated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for sticking with your question and editing it to get it into a form that we can work with! This is now a great question, and I hope you get the help you need. See this guide for [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into trouble because the data type returned by `data['activities'][0]` is very different from `data['activities'][:]`.

`data['activities'][0]` returns the first dictionary in the list:

```py
{
    "id":272961,
    "user_id":"izi57ti5",
    "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:09:53.830+00:00",
    "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:09:40.830+00:00"
}
```

On the other hand, any subset of the list, including `data['activities'][:10]` or `data['activities'][:]`, returns a list:

```py
>>> data['activities'][:]
[
      {
         "id":272961,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:09:53.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:09:40.830+00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":402616,
         "user_id":"izi57ti5",
         "answered_at":"2021-09-19T21:10:27.830+00:00",
         "first_seen_at":"2021-09-19T21:10:09.830+00:00"
      },
      ...
]
```

What you do with the result of this is to attempt to access the `'answered_at'` item from the dictionary. In the first case, this works fine:

```py
>>> data['activities'][0]['answered_at']
"2021-09-19T21:09:53.830+00:00"
```

But the second produces a TypeError, indicating that you can't access elements of a list using a string key, which is true.

Instead, you have to decide how you're going to modify your workflow to handle the many items within the list. For example, you could use a loop:

```py
for entry in data['activities']:
    # entry now points to the dictionaries within the list
    
    date1 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(entry['answered_at'])
    date2 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(entry['first_seen_at'])
    difference_date = (date1-date2)

    # this will print out once for every element in data['activities']
    print(
        "Duration in seconds:",
        difference_date.seconds,
        difference_date.microseconds,
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for the example and the whole explanation, and your time, now it works fine!